# 'Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree' while deleting firebase documents in flutter

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, dart

'**Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree**' while deleting firebase documents in flutter.i'm guessing because i'm having duplicate values in the fields. i'm not sure and also i don't know.

my app is working fine and also it is deleting the documents,if deleting unique values..the problem is my app crashes when it finds the duplicate value.

my code is...

```
 final _firestore=Firestore.instance;
void choiceAction(String choice){
  if(choice == dConstants.Settings){
    print('Settings');
  }
  if(choice == dConstants.delete){
      _firestore.collection('orders').getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.documents) {
          ds.reference.delete();
        }
      });
  }
}
```

and the error goes like this..

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree.

The following GlobalKeys were specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The keys were:
- [LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryState>#bdcb5]
  [LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryState>#902b8]
This was determined by noticing that after widgets with the above global keys were moved out of their previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widgets were moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with those global keys.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- Stack(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart, fit: expand, overflow: clip, dependencies: [Directionality], renderObject: RenderStack#9165c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2578:15)
#1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2603:8)
#2      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:775:18)
#3      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/FlutterNativeView(10759): FlutterView.send called on a detached view, channel=plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore
I/chatty  (10759): uid=10278(com.example.diet_manager) identical 18 lines
D/FlutterNativeView(10759): FlutterView.send called on a detached view, channel=plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore
D/FlutterNativeView(10759): FlutterView.send called on a detached view, channel=plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore
I/chatty  (10759): uid=10278(com.example.diet_manager) identical 8 lines
D/FlutterNativeView(10759): FlutterView.send called on a detached view, channel=plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore
```

Comment: are u using `globalkey` in your code?

Comment: no i'm not using any  global key